# Actionbar up button shown in the wrong location

Tags: android, android-actionbar, up-button

I'm running my application on 2 devices: Galaxy Nexus and Asus Transformer tf101.

On the G-N (4.2.2), the up button is shown BUT on the Transformer(4.0.3) it isn't.

**Any idea why this happens and how to overcome it?** Meaning, I'd like a consistant behavior - show the up button on both. Thanks.

**Update** - 12/May/2013: Setting the visibility to VISIBLE made the up button visible on the Transformer but it is located at the wrong place. See screenshot attached. WTF?

```
int upId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("up", "id", "android");
if (upId > 0) {
    ImageView up = (ImageView) findViewById(upId);
    up.setImageResource(drawable.actionbar_up);
    up.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

[image]

**Update** - 12/May/2013: As requested, initialization of the action bar. Very standard as you can see.

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setTitle(string.menu_settings);
getActionBar().setIcon(drawable.actionbar_logo);
```

Comment: [ActionbarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) is great for a consistent behavior on devices/versions that may not support the actionbar

Comment: I'm not using actionbarsherlock and wouldn't want to do the migration right now.

Comment: Did you set `getActionbar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true)` ? Please show the relevant portion of code used to setup the actionbar.

Comment: The code seems correct. Anyway please consider to not hack with views visibility and use the provided APIs instead. Have you tested your code on stock API11 (ICS) emulator?

Comment: With the hack, I was trying to show the up button - that's all. I tested my code on an emulator 4.0.3 (API level 15) and the result is the same. up icon located at the wrong place - right to the home button.